# TSLINT: How to blacklist "import * as" pattern

Tags: javascript, typescript, tslint

I want to blacklist `import as *` pattern for specific libs.

For instance:

```
import * as _ from 'lodash'; // <-- Should be blacklisted!

import { get } from 'lodash'; // Meant to be used instead
```

As far as I know `tslint` has [import-blacklist](https://palantir.github.io/tslint/rules/import-blacklist/) rule, but I'm not sure if it can be configurated that way.

P.S. I know that you could import loadash with submodules, like `lodash/get`, but what if I want to do it for some other libs?